# Stochastic walk on $\mathbb{N}$ is recurrent Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

We have a stochastic walk on $\mathbb{N}$ with $p_{i,i-1}=1$ for $i\geq 1$ and $p_{0,i}=p_i>0$ for all $i\geq 0$. Further we have $\sum p_i=1$ and $\sum ip_i<\infty$.

> How do I show that this Markov chain is recurrent?

I know that recurrent means that starting in state $i$ the chain will once return to $i$, or $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{t=1}^\infty\{X_t=i\}|X_0=i)=1$.
Further the chain is as follows, from each state we go with probability $1$ to the previous state and from $0$ we can go to any other state. So trivially, 0 is recurrent; and any other state $i$ will go to zero from which it can go to a state larger than $i$ and thus return to $i$. But how can I show this formally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Markov chain, there is a non-zero probability to get from any state in $\mathbb{N}$ to any other state in $\mathbb{N}$. (Check the details). This means that your Markov chain is *irreducible*. If you show that one state in an irreducible Markov chain is recurrent, that means that the entire Markov chain is a recurrent chain. Since you have shown that $0$ is a recurrent state, this implies that the entire Markov chain is recurrent.

To find the steady-state distribution, 
try solving the global balance equations, 
$$
\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N} - \{i\}} \pi_i p_{i,j} = \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N} - \{i\}} \pi_j p_{j,i}.
$$

Comment: This does not imply that the Markov chain is *positive recurrent*, which is necessary for a stationary distribution to exist (since the state space is infinite).

Comment: The chain could well be irreducible and null recurrent, in which case no stationary distribution exists.

Comment: A Markov process on a countable state space is positive recurrent if it is irreducible, recurrent, and has an invariant probability distribution -- as stated in this answer.

Comment: The existence of an invariant probability distribution is contingent on the process being positive recurrent. In this case, state $0$ is positive recurrent, and therefore the process is positive recurrent. But you did not state this in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The chain is irreducible as $p_{0i}>0$ for all $i$ and $p_{i-1,i}>0$ for all $i>0$, and is positive recurrent as the expected time between visits to $0$ is
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)p_i<\infty. $$ Therefore a unique stationary distribution exists.

The global balance equations are $$\pi_{n+1}+p_n\pi_0 = \pi_n, $$ which yields the recurrence $\pi_{n+1} = \pi_n-p_n\pi_0.$ By inspection we see that $$\pi_{n+1} = \pi_0\left(1-\sum_{i=0}^n p_i\right),\quad n\geqslant0. $$ Writing $1-\sum_{i=0}^n p_i = \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty p_i$ and using $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\pi_i = 1$, we have
$$1 = \pi_0\left(1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty p_i\right). $$
The $p_i$ are nonnegative, so using Tonelli's theorem we compute
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty p_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^i p_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty ip_i<\infty. $$
It follows that $$\pi_0 = \frac1{1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty ip_i} $$
and hence
$$\pi_{n+1} = \frac{\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty p_i}{1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty ip_i},\quad n\geqslant0. $$